# can't fetch json data based upon a particular id using ajax, jquery

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-ajax

I have an Index page which receives json data from my ASP.NET webapi. Code snippet of my index page along with jquery code.

> Index.cshtml

```
 <table id="meetings">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Subject</th>
                <th>Regarding</th>
                <th>Full Name</th>
                <th>Mobile</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>




<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $("#meetings").DataTable({
            ajax: {
                url: "/api/meetingrequest/",
                dataSrc: ""
            },
            columns: [
                {
                    data: "subject",
                    render: function (data, type, meeting) {
                     return "<a href='/home/details/" + meeting.id + " '>" + data + "</a>";

                    }

                },
                {
                    data: "requestAMeetingFor.name"
                },
                {
                    data: "fullName"
                },
                {
                    data: "mobileNumber"
                },
                {
                    data: "emailAddress"
                },

                }
            ]
        });
    });

</script>
```

This is perfectly working by generating a hyper link based on the id and fetching (and displaying) json data: 
    `<a href="/home/details/6 ">Driving</a>`

I verified the json data using "Postman" and I have it. However, My only problem is I am not able to show the data based upon that particular ID on another view, let say, When the link is clicked, it should take to a new view, for example,  Details and show data related to the particualr ID.I can see these data by ID in Postman.

[Json data by Postman -screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rDan.gif)

> Details.cshtml

```
 <table id="meetings" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Subject</th>
                <th>Regarding</th>
                <th>Full Name</th>
                <th>Mobile</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Message</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>


</div>
```

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $("#meetings").DataTable({

            ajax: {
                type:"GET",
                url: "/api/meetingrequest/" +id,
                dataType: 'JSON',
                dataSrc: ""
            },
            columns: [
                {
                    data: "subject"


                },
                {
                    data: "requestAMeetingFor.name"
                },
                {
                    data: "fullName"
                },
                {
                    data: "mobileNumber"
                },
                {
                    data: "emailAddress"
                },
                {
                    data: "message"

                }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Your help will be highly appreciated. 
p.s. I used Datatable for the index page, but won't use for this solution.

Comment: if you enter the url to browser bar  `http:/localhost/home/details/6` is it work?

Comment: No, When I enter the above link or click on the referenced link, nothings happen, as I have not written the view Details..actually I wrote it but that wasn't working coz I could not figure out how to pass the ID.

Comment: is my link right? plz post your code of details page.

Comment: Your link is right apart from missing port number ;) I mean my index page has a table with many data and one should be able to see detail view by clicking one hyper link. But when I click on it, I could not show the data using jquery/ajax but using postman, i can see I have data. Please see the included image.Thanks for reply.

Comment: so you've got ajax response successfully and links generated with the id's but where is the code to this details page, is it the same page.

Comment: i have a point to say: you have extra space after `<a href="/home/details/6 ">Driving</a>` try to replace the line to `return "<a href='/home/details/" + meeting.id + "'>" + data + "</a>";`

Comment: I have added the details page, I think the problem lies with the ajax url.